# "Even to me" or "even for me"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, to-for

> English prepositions are difficult even **for/to** me.

Which one is correct, *for* or *to*? Is there a difference? Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: This isn’t a duplicate of the question it’s been marked as a duplicate of. That question deals with the sentence fragment “for/to me” meaning “as regards me” or “as far as I’m concerned” or “in my opinion”. This one deals with which preposition the adjective _difficult_ prefers to be collocated with. Different kettle of fish altogether.

Comment: @Sabrina H: Climbing Everest is not easy to do, even for a *sherpa*.  Those scribbles on the wall make no sense, even to an Egyptologist.  The verb-phrase in the first clause determines the preposition in the second.  is difficult for, is comprehensible to, and so on.